# How can I have a custom background and cell for Facebook iOS Friend Picker with segue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook

I am using the SDK of Facebook to show the users friends. But I don't know how to change the white background of the table when I call the segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueToFriendPicker"]) {

        FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = (FBFriendPickerViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
        friendPickerController.doneButton = nil;
        friendPickerController.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
        friendPickerController.delegate = self;
        [friendPickerController loadData];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From FBFriendPickerViewController documentation:

```
When the FBFriendPickerViewController view loads it creates a UITableView
object where the friends will be displayed. You can access this view through
the tableView property.
```

This might work:

```
friendPickerController.tableView.backgroundColor = /*YOUR COLOUR HERE*/;
```